# How to manually remove hitarea when using jQuery TreeView plugin

Tags: jquery, treeview

Is there a way to manually remove the "hitarea" (+/-) from an item while using this plugin?  I have attempted finding the desired node and executing `$(this).removeClass('expandable');` etc. etc.  I have tried removing `expandable, collapsable, lastExpandable, lastCollapsable, hitarea`; no difference.  Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind :).  I was able to handle this by modifying the way that the uls are built.

Comment: @Andrew (I believe) What I ended up doing was to just restructure the way that the tree was built so that if an entry was not to be expandable, it was an `<li>` and not a `<ul>`.  It was a pain in the ass given the dynamic nature of the data but I was able to get it going.  I doubt that that helps in your case.  Let me know if I can help otherwise.